# How to fix this error on PDO statements: Invalid parameter number?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to a PDO using the following code:

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

# cartexe.php will perform all actions on cart.php

// add Item to Cart
if(isset($_POST['addItemToCart']))
{
    // initialize index.php variables
    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // check the cart table to see if the product has been previously added
    $smtp = $conn->prepare('SELECT Quantity FROM cart WHERE Product Name = :product'); // prepare a statement to fetch the quantity for a particular product... the statement is not executed but merely prepared to do so. 
    $smtp->bindParam(':product', $productName, PDO::PARAM_STR); //bind the productName with whatever data supplied hence the statement after : above will be replaced with the actually data.. In additional the statement is set as string hence PDO::PRAM_STR
    $smtp->execute();//finally run the statment

    $result = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if($result > 0)
   {
     echo " DATA FOUND";
   }
   else
   {
      echo ' No data founded';
   }

}

?>
```

But I keep getting the error below. I have tried several different methods but none of them worked.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your column name in backticks since it contains a space

```
WHERE `Product Name`
```

having used `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, would have signaled an error.

Another option is to use an underscore between the words while renaming/altering your column to `Product_Name`

```
WHERE Product_Name ...
```

---

*An insight:*

Also make sure your form element is indeed named.

I.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="productName">
```

---

Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and placed at the top of your file(s):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

would signal (other) possible errors also, should it be the case.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated it!